# Using cURL and foreach, huge loading time

Tags: php, curl, time, foreach, loading

I have the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
set_time_limit(1000);

$f = $_GET['location'].'.txt';

if ( !file_exists($f) ) {
die('Location unavailable');
}

$file = fopen($f, "r");

$i = 0;
while (!feof($file)) {
    $members[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);

    function get_thumbs($url)
    {
       $ch = curl_init();

       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

       ob_start();

       curl_exec ($ch);
       curl_close ($ch);
       $string = ob_get_contents();

       ob_end_clean();

       return $string;

    }
foreach ($members as $id){
//    echo $id.'<br/>'; // do something with each line from text file here
$id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $id);


    $link = 'http://localhost/cvr/get.php?id='.$id.'&thumb=yes&title=yes';
    $content = get_thumbs($link);

echo $content;
        }

?>
```

Where get.php is using almost the same above cURL function to grab data from a website and parse it.

In the txt file I have like 20 ids to get data from but the foreach seems to take a very long time to load, like 30+ seconds. Any advice?
I am a php beginner so please don't be very hard on me.
Thanks!